# Operating PowerShell inside an application?

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell, powershell-3.0

I want to make an executable that contains a collection of PowerShell scripts.  On the left hand side the user could see a list of different scripts to select and run, and on the right hand side would be the output.

If I have a basic wpf app that looks like the following: [image]

Would I be able to create an instance of PowerShell inside the right portion of the window?

i.e. something like this: [image]

The output window (the right side) would pretty much just be for the output of whatever script was run.

Before I get too invested in this idea though, is it even possible to run/output PowerShell scripts inside a window of a WPF application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a series of posts about using PowerShell from inside a .net app at my blog [PowerShellStation.com](http://powershellstation.com/category/writing-a-host/) (Writing a Host)

Comment: I should mention that the posts are about WinForms, but the principles are the same.